# I want to return a specific field value from a MongoDB document, but I keep getting [object Promise] as a return value instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to return a field value for a document in mongoose. I have a recipe schema and in it, I outlined a value called "postedBy" that is basically the _id of the person who submitted the recipe. Here is the code for the recipe model:

```
let recipeSchema = new Schema({

  // I have other values in the schema, but for clarity sake, 
  // I clearly have the field value defined in the schema model. 

  postedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  }

});
```

Now here is the code where I am having problems:

```
  /// Here I make my function that returns the postedBy field value in 
 ///question

    let getRecipeMaker = (recipeId) => {

       return Recipe

           .findOne({_id: recipeId})
           .then((recipe) => {
                /// So far this is good, this console.log is printing out 
                /// the field value I want
                console.log('What is being returned is ' + recipe.postedBy);
               return recipe.postedBy;
           })
           .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
           });
    };


    // Then here, I am setting the returned result of the function to a 
    // variable. My req.params.recipeId is already outlined
    // in the router this code is in, so that's not the issue.

    let value_ = getRecipeMaker(req.params.recipeId)
        .then((chef) => {


            // This console.log is printing the value that I want to the 
            // console. So I should get it.
            console.log('chef is ' + chef);



        });



    /// But whenever I am console.logging the variable, I keep getting 
   ///[object Promise] instead of the value I want
    console.log('value_ is ' + value_);
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Looks like you already know the solution - put the code that uses the value in a `then` callback?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in the way you are working with promises.  Your final console log is outside of the promise chain.  Your final console.log actually executes before the database has a chance to query the results.  If you wanted the scope to be outside the promise you could return chef after you get your recipe maker

```
let value_ = getRecipeMaker(req.params.recipeId)
    .then((chef) => {


        // This console.log is printing the value that I want to the 
        // console. So I should get it.
        console.log('chef is ' + chef);
        return chef;


    });
```

then where your final console log is

```
value_.then(chef => {
  console.log(chef);
});
```

Comment: If I want to use value_ variable for other purposes, should I put the code inside that value_.then() promise or can I use it outside of it?

Comment: You have to put the code inside of the then function.  Typically all promise based programming will look like that.  I would recommend studying the promise coding styles a bit more.